# Move Express middleware to separate modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I have lots of `app.use(...)` in my express app, and they get messy and complex and there's config all over the place. So I want to move them to separate modules so they're easier to test.

So I have this `Middleware.ts` base class for my middleware wrappers:

```
export default abstract class Middleware {

  public run(): express.RequestHandler {
    try {
      return this.runImpl;
    }
    catch (err) {
      log("Failed to init middleware " + err);
      throw err;
    }
  }

  public abstract runImpl(): express.RequestHandler;

}
```

And a subclass, e.g. `StaticMiddleware.ts` for serving static files:

```
export class StaticMiddleware extends Middleware {

  public runImp(): express.RequestHandler {
    // this is a simple example, but most middleware are more
    // complicated, but everything is encapsulated here
    return express.static("path");
  }

}

export default new StaticMiddleware().run;
```

Finally the `app.ts` express app itself, which is very clean:

```
import staticMiddleware from "./StaticMiddleware";
import fooMiddleware from "./FooMiddleware";
import barMiddleware from "./BarMiddleware";

app.use(staticMiddleware());
app.use(fooMiddleware());
app.use(barMiddleware());
```

But I get an error at runtime:

> TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function

---

Note it's possible to change the method signatures above, so I can use this form:

```
app.use(staticMiddleware);
```

But that is surprising to a maintainer, and so liable to break. I want the normal signature:

```
app.use(staticMiddleware());
```

Comment: You want to stick to typescript I guess? I'm really not good at it, but coming back to your original question, why don't you just move the request handlers themselves (the `(req,res,next) => ()` functions) to a separate module?

Comment: @user826955 Yeah I want to use TS. The way I've written it offers better encapsulation and is easier to test. I'm sure it's possible, I just can't get the syntax right.

Comment: Okay then I think I cannot help, because I'm not familiar with it. I don't quite get why you need a class concept for this, so dunno. BTW I did not downvote, but I upvoted so youre at 0 again ;)

Comment: @user826955 Thanks for your advice and your upvote! :)